# Push notification stopped working for IOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

I have my application signed using enterprise certificate which supports push notification feature in it. It was working fine and when I updated iphone to iOS 8 push notification stopped working. After I debug and little research I came to know that following code to be added to retrieve push token from iOS 8 onwards.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) //>iOS8
{
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}else {// <iOS8
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

}

Add following callback methods,

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
     [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
    //handle the actions
}
```

However we do not face this problem with appstore version of our application and all working good. Is it something broken on enterprise certification only?

Comment: have you add "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" in your info.plist file?

Comment: is it really require for push notification?

Comment: yes. is it. otherwise app will not able to receive push notification. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html)                    check this line in Discussion  section: " The user prompt contains the text from the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required when calling this method."

Comment: check this also [link](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: so… any update from you?

Comment: @iphoneDev what do you mean by adding this key in the info.plist? what should I do exactly?

Comment: @roi.holtzman have you check this [link] (http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/) in this link already mention that in ios 8 you have to add this two keys in info.plist file. so check this link again.                                                                                                                    
    NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or
    NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Answer (score 0):

You are forgeting a line code:   `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];`

something like this:

```
if ([application respondsToSelector: selector (registerUserNotificationSettings :)]) {
      UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                               categories: nil ];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
   } else {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

   }
```